# Did Starlink's experimental Darksat help reduce brightness?

Tags: spacex, starlink, satellite-constellation, astronomy

Did Darksat's visor like coverings to its parabolic antennas reduce the brightness or was it a failure.
Or is SpaceX devoleping any other mechanisms or manuveres to counter this problem?

Comment: I think Starlinks have flat phased array antennas, but I'm not sure what surfaces contributed most to making them reflective. Flatter surfaces lead to flaring, but why they are visible other times I don't know.